# Set the Java bean validation message dynamically in Spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have a bean defined as below:

```
public class PostDTO {
    @Autowired
    private Messages messages;  

    private String id;

    @Size(min = Constant.POST_TITLE_MIN_LEN, max = Constant.POST_TITLE_MAX_LEN, message = messages.get("post.err.title"))
    private String title;
}
```

I want the `message` value to be dynamic based on locale. Above code shows `The value for annotation attribute Size.message must be a constant expression` error.

Comment: May I know why did you use `@Autowired` in EntityClass?

Answer (score 0):

I think you could use SpEL (Spring Expression Language)

```java
public class PostDTO {

    private String id;

    @Size(min = Constant.POST_TITLE_MIN_LEN, max = Constant.POST_TITLE_MAX_LEN, message = "#{'${post.err.title}'}")
    private String title;
}
```

and define the variable in spring properties file like:
`post.err.title = “Post Error”`

More details for SpEL: https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.3.10.RELEASE/spring-framework-reference/html/expressions.html

Comment: it doesn't work